# display a staff_reg form in a manager_dash form's panel when inside staff_details a button called register_satff is clicked

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, project

I have 3 forms: manager_dashboard, staff_details, and staff_registration. I have connected the staff details form using a panel in the manager dashboard. Now I want to open a new form when I click a button inside staff details in the manager dashboard panel.

```
Manager_Dashboard md = new Manager_Dashboard();
Delete_Satff ds = new Delete_Satff();
ds.TopLevel = false;
md.pnl_view.Controls.Add(ds);
ds.BringToFront();
ds.Show();
```

Comment: Do you have any updates?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define a public method in the child window and call it in the main window.

See the code below for details:

Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            form2.Show();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            form2.OpenFomr3();
        }
    }
}
```

Form2:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public void OpenFomr3()
        {
            Form3 form3 = new Form3();
            form3.TopLevel = false;
            form3.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(form3);
            form3.Show();
        }

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

OutPut:

[image]